# Find text in two columns

Tags: excel

Is there any Excel function that would help in finding different certain letters in 2 columns?

For instance:

```
A      B
SSS   NNN
BBB   HHH
DDD   USS
GGG   PPP
DDD   SSS
DDD   USS
DDD   NNN
```

I would like to run a function like:

If any cell that contains any word with S as first letter in column A AND N as a first letter in the column B return "null" else return the result"*** ***"

```
if(LEFT A=D & B=U) return *** *** the result...
```

The result is

```
DDD USS
DDD USS
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes there is.  Combine `IF` and `LEFT`.  Or use a filter.  Show us the formula you come up with and the results for help. Also, please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This question would be better suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the =AND() function inside the IF() function.

```
=IF(AND(LEFT(A1,1)="D",LEFT(B1,1)="U"),A1 & " " & B1,"")
```

Put it in cell C1 and pull all the way down.

I'm not sure I completely understand what you mean though with the expected result... You can use the results e.g. to filter your data, if you only need the specified rows.

Comment: Your result does not match that shown under Results in the question

Comment: @RonRosenfeld yep, and his result shown in the question doesn't fit the description in the question... Hard to tell what he wants. If he is any good in Excel, this could get him started, or now he can clarify what he needs.

Comment: His results look like the result of using a simple filter.

Comment: But... Nobody is THAT new to Excel... Or... ?

Comment: Some are.  And, as you point out, a different forum might be better suited.  But you could use a simple filter without any formulas to achieve his results